# Pointcut "or" composition in Spring AOP

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I have a class `BigManPlay` implements an interface `Performance`:

```
@Component
public class BigManPlay implements Performance {
    @Override
    public void perform() {
        System.out.println("Performing 111!");
    }

    @Override
    public void perform2() {
        System.out.println("Performing 222!");
    }
}
```

Then, I expect the `perform()` method and every method(means `perform2()`) in the `Performance` interface are the advice targets. So I write the following aspect class:

```
@Aspect
public class Audience {

    @Pointcut("execution(* Chapter_4_2_1.concert.Performance.perform(..)) or within(Chapter_4_2_1.concert.Performance+)")
    public void performance() {}

    @Before("performance()")
    public void silenceCellPhones() {
        System.out.println("Silencing cell phones");
    }
    @Before("performance()")
    public void takeSeats() {
        System.out.println("Taking seats");
    }
    @AfterReturning("performance()")
    public void applause() {
        System.out.println("CLAP CLAP CLAP!!!");
    }
}
```

Then a java config class to wire beans:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"Chapter_4_2_1.concert"})
public class ConcertConfig {
    @Bean
    public Audience audience() {
        return new Audience();
    }
}
```

Then the UT class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes=ConcertConfig.class)
public class PerformanceTest {

    @Autowired
    Performance bigManPlay;

    @Rule
    public final SystemOutRule log = new SystemOutRule().enableLog();

    @Test
    public void testWithPerformance() {
        log.clearLog();
        bigManPlay.perform();
        assertEquals("Silencing cell phones" + System.lineSeparator()
                + "Taking seats" + System.lineSeparator()
                + "Performing 111!" + System.lineSeparator()
                + "CLAP CLAP CLAP!!!" + System.lineSeparator(), log.getLog());
    }


    @Test
    public void testWithPerformance2() {
        log.clearLog();
        bigManPlay.perform2();
        assertEquals("Silencing cell phones" + System.lineSeparator()
            + "Taking seats" + System.lineSeparator()
            + "Performing 222!" + System.lineSeparator()
            + "CLAP CLAP CLAP!!!" + System.lineSeparator(), log.getLog());
    }
}
```

UT is failed. `testWithPerformance2()` only output

```
Performing 222!
```

The `within(Chapter_4_2_1.concert.Performance+)` doesn't take effect, why?

Answer (score 0):

[The syntax for pointcut composition for "or" is `||`](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/progguide/printable.html#quick-pointcuts).

> `Pointcut0 || Pointcut1`  each join point picked out by either `Pointcut0`
>   or `Pointcut1`

That will look like

```
@Pointcut("execution(* Chapter_4_2_1.concert.Performance.perform(..)) || within(Chapter_4_2_1.concert.Performance+)")
```

Essentially the parser finds the first pointcut expression, the `execution`, and stops parsing because there are no other composition tokens in the remaining expression. You could write anything

```
@Pointcut("execution(* Chapter_4_2_1.concert.Performance.perform(..)) blabla")
```

and it wouldn't fail to parse. It would create a valid pointcut for that `execution`.